# DownloadManager queue - start time

Tags: android, download, android-download-manager

i have an aplication that allows people to make updates of their own aplications. It uses download manager and uses the "DownloadManager" queue. The problem is that i want to monitor when the download starts and ends (the time that the download lasted).

I have a receiver to check when the download ends, but how do i know when it started since it is on the queue ?

If i knew when his time arrives on the queue, i could start counting the time.

What could be a possible solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to query the `DownloadManager` for updates:

```java
DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
query.setFilterById(downloadId);
  // downloadId is returned to you upon DownloadManager.enqueue

Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(query);
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    try {
        int status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
        // Decide what to do with it
        // Status are defined as constants in DownloadManager.STATUS_*
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but in this case i would have to be doing that like every second which wouldn't be eficient. I guess there is no solution for what i want, because this DownloadManager doesn't have that option.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there is a straight solution for that. DownloadManager does not broadcast those status changes as far as I know.